Any Idea that How do I bring this table to the upper page?
I am writing a report on latex and I encountered an issue. When I was making my table using 'tblr' from tabular array package, I found out that my table that is supposed to clearly fit in the current page goes to next page and funnily remains the same size it was supposed to be in 1st page. How do i fix this wierd issue?
This is the page where I want the table to start:

This is the page that is formed after the above.

Clearly the table does not fit the full page and goes to next page early. The table in this page was clearly generated to fit in the page above. Why is it going to next page and how do I fix it?
This is the code I am using:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Load hyperref last
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[indent=0.75\parindent]{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\section{Method}
\vspace{30mm}
\subsection{Data}
From Cambridge Dictionary, data is information, especially facts or numbers, collected to be examined and considered and used to help decision-making, or information in an electronic form that can be stored and used by a computer. There are two ways to collect data which are primary (direct) and secondary (indirect). Wagh. S (2022) stated that primary data is data generated by the researcher, such as surveys, interviews, and experimental research, which are specifically designed to help the researcher understand and in order to address the research source of the problem. Whereas secondary data is data which has already been managed to gather for another purpose (Allen. M, 2017). For instance, the data from World Bank, Government, journal, etc.

On this occasion, secondary data is a method that is used for collecting the data since this research needs to be valid and wide that can't be obtained by using direct methods that surely will consume plenty of time and cost. There are a lot of resources available but this research needs credibility and objectivity.

There are several benefit by using secondary data, which are

\begin{enumerate}
  \item It is cost-effective. It saves both time and money.
  \item It saves you time.
  \item It aids in making primary data collection more specific because secondary data allows us to identify gaps and deficiencies, as well as what additional information needs to be collected.
  \item It contributes to a better understanding of the problem.
  \item It serves as a foundation for comparing the data gathered by the researcher.
\end{enumerate}

However, there is also disadvantages of using secondary data, which are

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Secondary data rarely fits within the framework of marketing research factors.
  \item The precision of secondary data is unknown.
  \item Data may be out of date.
\end{enumerate}

In this case, to minimize time spending, secondary data is used as the resources since there are millions of lip products in Indonesia. \href{http://My-best.id}{My-best.id} website is a website that provides information about recommended products. With \href{http://My-best.id}{My-best.id}, people can easily find the best goods in some country without analyzing it one by one since it also provides a comparison table. However, to avoid irrelevant data, gaining some primary data from official websites is used to ensure that the data is credible and valid. Below is the table showing the population.

\begin{center}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}
    \begin{tblr}[long, label={Table1}, caption={Population of Lip Products in Indonesia}]{colspec={l | c | c | c | c}, rowhead=1, hlines={}}
        \textbf{Lip Product} & \textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Type of Lip Product} & \textbf{Shades} & \textbf{Price} \\ 
        NIVEA LIP BALM SOOTHE \& PROTECT & Beiersdorf & Stick & 1 & 29000 \\
        Extra lip tint & Bobbi Brown & Stick & 7 & 345000 \\
        Perfect Matte Lip Coat & Dear Me Beauty & Liquid & 6 & 129000 \\
        Creamytint & Emina & Liquid & 5 & 44000 \\
        magic potion lip tint & Emina & Liquid & 6 & 46000 \\
        Squeeze me up Lip Matte & Emina & Liquid & 4 & 53500 \\
        Smoochies Lip balm & Emina & Solid & 2 & 30500 \\
        Matte Lip Liquid & ESQA & Liquid & 7 & 165000 \\
        Dear Darling Water gel tint & Etude House & Liquid & 10 & 35000 \\
        Organic lip balm & Eucalie & Stick & 1 & 79000 \\
        lip and cheek dual use liquid & Focallure & Liquid & 7 & 129045 \\
        Melted Matte Lip & Goban Cosmetics & Liquid & 5 & 78000 \\
        Sheen. Tinted lip balm + UV filter & HALE. & Stick & 3 & 98000 \\
        Urban Lip Cream Matte & Implora & Liquid & 12 & 24000 \\
        Beauty Lip \& Cheeck Crayon & Indoganic & Crayon & 3 & 129000 \\
        Vivid oil tint & Innisfree & Liquid & 10 & 150000 \\
        Metallic Lip Cream & Inul Beauty & Liquid & 4 & 89000 \\
        Infalible Pro Matte Lip Liquid & L'oreal & Liquid & 4 & 150000 \\
        Rouge Signature Liquid Matte Lipstick & L'oreal & Liquid & 10 & 150000 \\
        Color Riche Matte & L'oreal & Stick & 45 & 75000 \\
        Intense Matte Lip Cream & Liquid & Liquid & 12 & 110000 \\
        Longlasting Matte Lip Cream Metalic & LT Pro & Liquid & 3 & 97500 \\
        Ultra Light Lip Stain & Luxcrime & Liquid & 5 & 109000 \\
        Airy lip mousse & Luxcrime & Liquid & 8 & 109000 \\
        Dew tinted 6hr lip moisturizer & Mad for Makeup & Stick & 3 & 99000 \\
        magnifique lip tint & Madame Gie & Liquid & 8 & 23000 \\
        Brilliant Glaze Lip Liquide & Madame Gie & Liquid & 5 & 27000 \\
        Moist Velvet \& Smooth Lip Liquide & Madame Gie & Liquid & 6 & 30000 \\
        Hydrastay lip whip & Makeover & liquid & 12 & 105000 \\
        Powestay Transfer Proof Matte Lip & Makeover & Liquid & 8 & 123000 \\
        Sensational Liquid Matte & Maybelline & Liquid & 10 & 69000 \\
        color sensational lip tint & Maybelline & Liquid & 5 & 119000 \\
        Super Stay Matte Ink & Maybelline & Liquid & 44 & 125000 \\
        Color sensational the powder & Maybelline mattes & stick & 24 & 55000 \\
        Hydra Lip Cheek Tint & Mineral Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 51900 \\
        the one A-Z lip balm SPF 25 & Oriflame & Stick & 2 & 139000 \\
        Lip Cream & PIXY & Liquid & 16 & 53700 \\
        2 in 1 color tint & Purbasari & Liquid & 3 & 38500 \\
        Lip Cream Series & Raiku & Liquid & 13 & 118000 \\
        SUEDED! Lip \& Cheek Cream & Rollover Reaction & Liquid & 12 & 129000 \\
        Juicy Lip Balm & Rose All day & Stick & 4 & 139000 \\
        Lip Color & Runa Beauty & Stick & 5 & 138000 \\
        Lip Care & Sensatia Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 60000 \\
        Coconut lip sleeping balm & Tiff Body & Liquid & 1 & 69000 \\
        delight tony tint & Tony Moly & Liquid & 3 & 28000 \\
        Exclusive Matte Lip Cream & Wardah & Liquid & 20 & 62000 \\
        Colorfit Velvet Matte Lip Mousse & Wardah & Liquid & 14 & 73000 \\
        Everyday Moisture Lip nutrition & Wardah & Stick & 2 & 27000 \\
        Color Fit Ultralight Matte & Wardah & stick & 5 & 43000 \\
        The Simplicity Love You tint & Y.O.U & Liquid & 6 & 45000 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{center}

\subsection{Sampling}
Momoh. 0 (2021) stated that a population is a distinguishable group of people, whether that group is a nation or group of people who represent a characteristic. In this research the population is all the population data of popular lip products in Indonesia including several types. Whereas sampling is a technique for selecting individual members or a subset of the population in order to make statistical inferences and estimate population characteristics. From the population of 50 lip products, divided by five variables which are lip product, brand, type, shades and price. There are four methods of sampling which are random, stratified, systematic and cluster sampling. Stratified sampling method is used to determine the sample in this research by dividing the population into subgroups based on the brand. There are 35 data collections for samples.

The confidence interval is $95 \%$ with level of significance one-tailed test is 0.025 and level of significance two-tailed test is 0.05 . Below is the table showing the sample.

\begin{center}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}
    \begin{tblr}[long, label={Table2}, caption={Sample of Lip Products in Indonesia}]{colspec={l | c | c | c | c}, rowhead=1, hlines={}}
        \textbf{Lip Product} & \textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Type of Lip Product} & \textbf{Shades} & \textbf{Price} \\ 
        NIVEA LIP BALM SOOTHE \& PROTECT & Beiersdorf & Stick & 1 & 29000 \\
        Extra lip tint & Bobbi Brown & Stick & 7 & 345000 \\
        Perfect Matte Lip Coat & Dear Me Beauty & Liquid & 6 & 129000 \\
        Creamytint & Emina & Liquid & 5 & 44000 \\
        Matte Lip Liquid & ESQA & Liquid & 7 & 165000 \\
        Dear Darling Water gel tint & Etude House & Liquid & 10 & 35000 \\
        Organic lip balm & Eucalie & Stick & 1 & 79000 \\
        lip and cheek dual use liquid & Focallure & Liquid & 7 & 129045 \\
        Melted Matte Lip Sheen & Goban & Liquid & 5 & 78000 \\
        Tinted lip balm + UV filter & HALE. & Stick & 3 & 98000 \\
        Urban Lip Cream Matte & Implora & Liquid & 12 & 24000 \\
        Beauty Lip \& Cheeck Crayon & Indoganic & Crayon & 3 & 129000 \\
        Vivid oil tint & Innisfree & Liquid & 10 & 150000 \\
        Metallic Lip Cream & Inul Beauty & Liquid & 4 & 89000 \\
        Infalible Pro Matte Lip Liquid & L'oreal & Liquid & 4 & 150000 \\
        Intense Matte Lip Cream & Liquid & Liquid & 12 & 110000 \\
        Longlasting Matte Lip Cream Metalic & LT Pro & Liquid & 3 & 97500 \\
        Ultra Light Lip Stain & Luxcrime & Liquid & 5 & 109000 \\
        Dew tinted 6hr lip moisturizer & Mad for & Stick & 3 & 99000 \\
        magnifique lip tint & Madame Gie & Liquid & 8 & 23000 \\
        Powestay Transfer Proof Matte & Makeover & Liquid & 8 & 123000 \\
        Sensational Liquid Matte & Maybelline & Liquid & 10 & 69000 \\
        Hydra Lip Cheek Tint & Mineral Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 51900 \\
        The one A-Z lip balm SPF 25 & Oriflame & Stick & 2 & 139000 \\
        Lip Cream & PIXY & Liquid & 16 & 53700 \\
        2 in 1 color tint & Purbasari & Liquid & 3 & 38500 \\
        Lip Cream Series & Raiku & Liquid & 13 & 118000 \\
        SUEDED! Lip \& Cheek Cream & Rollover Reaction & Liquid & 12 & 129000 \\
        Juicy Lip Balm & Rose All day & Stick & 4 & 139000 \\
        Lip Color & Runa Beauty & Stick & 5 & 138000 \\
        Lip Care & Sensatia Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 60000 \\
        Coconut lip sleeping balm & Tiff Body & Liquid & 1 & 69000 \\
        delight tony tint & Tony Moly & Liquid & 3 & 28000 \\
        Exclusive Matte Lip Cream & Wardah & Liquid & 20 & 62000 \\
        The Simplicity Love You tint & Y.O.U & Liquid & 6 & 45000 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Also I feel like mentioning that this is working just fine in the same document in another table.

Update:: I am attaching the full code.
Update:: Here, is the log file:
Link for log file

Welcome to TeX.SE!

please fix the example to show the problem, you are asking about page breaking, so should show a small complete document that has the bad page break that you show. Don't make people guess how to wrap that code in a document that produces a bad break.

I apologize! I have uploaded the full code

If I test your code with an up-to-date texlive 2024, I get the table on the same page as the text

@JohnKormylo, That command is just for shifting the table left since it is very large. I did not understand what change you want me to do

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Umm, I use Ubuntu 22.04 and have texlive from apt installed. I compile using the pdflatex command. My system is pretty much up to date

Can you share your .log file?

Your tables are too wide for the margins (use [draft]).  The right side will push into the margin regardless of centering.  OTOH, this does not seem to affect the page breaks.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have added the log file

@JohnKormylo You are right! But I have to do the adjusting to make file look. What other choice do I have. I can't have a shorter table can I?

\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{-3cm} and lose the center environment (redundant).

@mr.hello291 I can reproduce your problem with texlive 2021. It works fine starting with a fully updated texlive 2022 or newer. Try to update your ancient texlive version. If you use vanilla texlive from tug.org you get an up to date version instead of these long outdated versions included in linux.

@JohnKormylo Well, it still is producing same issue even though some issues on compilation are gone. Do tabular array environments center themselves automatically? Why does just adjusting widths from both sides also centers the table?

According to section 4.3, the halign keyword can be used to align an entire long table (default is justify, whatever that means), as well as individual cells, rows and columns.  Longtable is definitely self centering.

A bit late, but anyway it should help you ...

Testing your MWE gives expecting result: table start on the first page and since it is to big that can be fit on one page, so it continue on the next page.
considering above comment, it is not clear, what is your problem, so below are some opinion based suggestions:

by default a longtblr is centered in the text area or in a locally changed tetbarea (as you do by using the adjustwidth environment)
table can be narrowed by reduce of size the colsep for example to 3pt and use \small font size. By this the locally change of the text width is not need anymore.
remove vertical lines
remove the most of horizontal lines
change columns types (see MWE below)
use siunitx package (it should be loaded as tabularray library) for writing numbers in the last two columns as well for writing quantities in text on more proper way
not use capital letters for product name
make third columns title shorter


Above suggestion I consider only at your second table that you can compare result of suggested changes with your original designed table.
I also would thinking about make the text area wider, for example by use of the geometry packages.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[indent=0.75\parindent]{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{url} it is loaded by hyperref package
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Load hyperref last

\begin{document}
\section{Method}
\vspace{30mm}
\subsection{Data}
From Cambridge Dictionary, data is information, especially facts or numbers, collected to be examined and considered and used to help decision-making, or information in an electronic form that can be stored and used by a computer. There are two ways to collect data which are primary (direct) and secondary (indirect). Wagh. S (2022) stated that primary data is data generated by the researcher, such as surveys, interviews, and experimental research, which are specifically designed to help the researcher understand and in order to address the research source of the problem. Whereas secondary data is data which has already been managed to gather for another purpose (Allen. M, 2017). For instance, the data from World Bank, Government, journal, etc.

On this occasion, secondary data is a method that is used for collecting the data since this research needs to be valid and wide that can't be obtained by using direct methods that surely will consume plenty of time and cost. There are a lot of resources available but this research needs credibility and objectivity.

There are several benefit by using secondary data, which are

\begin{enumerate}
  \item It is cost-effective. It saves both time and money.
  \item It saves you time.
  \item It aids in making primary data collection more specific because secondary data allows us to identify gaps and deficiencies, as well as what additional information needs to be collected.
  \item It contributes to a better understanding of the problem.
  \item It serves as a foundation for comparing the data gathered by the researcher.
\end{enumerate}

However, there is also disadvantages of using secondary data, which are

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Secondary data rarely fits within the framework of marketing research factors.
  \item The precision of secondary data is unknown.
  \item Data may be out of date.
\end{enumerate}

In this case, to minimize time spending, secondary data is used as the resources since there are millions of lip products in Indonesia. \href{http://My-best.id}{My-best.id} website is a website that provides information about recommended products. With \href{http://My-best.id}{My-best.id}, people can easily find the best goods in some country without analyzing it one by one since it also provides a comparison table. However, to avoid irrelevant data, gaining some primary data from official websites is used to ensure that the data is credible and valid. Below is the table showing the population.

\begin{center}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}
    \begin{tblr}[long, label={Table1}, caption={Population of Lip Products in Indonesia}]{colspec={l | c | c | c | c}, rowhead=1, hlines={}}
        \textbf{Lip Product} & \textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Type of Lip Product} & \textbf{Shades} & \textbf{Price} \\
        NIVEA LIP BALM SOOTHE \& PROTECT & Beiersdorf & Stick & 1 & 29000 \\
        Extra lip tint & Bobbi Brown & Stick & 7 & 345000 \\
        Perfect Matte Lip Coat & Dear Me Beauty & Liquid & 6 & 129000 \\
        Creamytint & Emina & Liquid & 5 & 44000 \\
        magic potion lip tint & Emina & Liquid & 6 & 46000 \\
        Squeeze me up Lip Matte & Emina & Liquid & 4 & 53500 \\
        Smoochies Lip balm & Emina & Solid & 2 & 30500 \\
        Matte Lip Liquid & ESQA & Liquid & 7 & 165000 \\
        Dear Darling Water gel tint & Etude House & Liquid & 10 & 35000 \\
        Organic lip balm & Eucalie & Stick & 1 & 79000 \\
        lip and cheek dual use liquid & Focallure & Liquid & 7 & 129045 \\
        Melted Matte Lip & Goban Cosmetics & Liquid & 5 & 78000 \\
        Sheen. Tinted lip balm + UV filter & HALE. & Stick & 3 & 98000 \\
        Urban Lip Cream Matte & Implora & Liquid & 12 & 24000 \\
        Beauty Lip \& Cheeck Crayon & Indoganic & Crayon & 3 & 129000 \\
        Vivid oil tint & Innisfree & Liquid & 10 & 150000 \\
        Metallic Lip Cream & Inul Beauty & Liquid & 4 & 89000 \\
        Infalible Pro Matte Lip Liquid & L'oreal & Liquid & 4 & 150000 \\
        Rouge Signature Liquid Matte Lipstick & L'oreal & Liquid & 10 & 150000 \\
        Color Riche Matte & L'oreal & Stick & 45 & 75000 \\
        Intense Matte Lip Cream & Liquid & Liquid & 12 & 110000 \\
        Longlasting Matte Lip Cream Metalic & LT Pro & Liquid & 3 & 97500 \\
        Ultra Light Lip Stain & Luxcrime & Liquid & 5 & 109000 \\
        Airy lip mousse & Luxcrime & Liquid & 8 & 109000 \\
        Dew tinted 6hr lip moisturizer & Mad for Makeup & Stick & 3 & 99000 \\
        magnifique lip tint & Madame Gie & Liquid & 8 & 23000 \\
        Brilliant Glaze Lip Liquide & Madame Gie & Liquid & 5 & 27000 \\
        Moist Velvet \& Smooth Lip Liquide & Madame Gie & Liquid & 6 & 30000 \\
        Hydrastay lip whip & Makeover & liquid & 12 & 105000 \\
        Powestay Transfer Proof Matte Lip & Makeover & Liquid & 8 & 123000 \\
        Sensational Liquid Matte & Maybelline & Liquid & 10 & 69000 \\
        color sensational lip tint & Maybelline & Liquid & 5 & 119000 \\
        Super Stay Matte Ink & Maybelline & Liquid & 44 & 125000 \\
        Color sensational the powder & Maybelline mattes & stick & 24 & 55000 \\
        Hydra Lip Cheek Tint & Mineral Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 51900 \\
        the one A-Z lip balm SPF 25 & Oriflame & Stick & 2 & 139000 \\
        Lip Cream & PIXY & Liquid & 16 & 53700 \\
        2 in 1 color tint & Purbasari & Liquid & 3 & 38500 \\
        Lip Cream Series & Raiku & Liquid & 13 & 118000 \\
        SUEDED! Lip \& Cheek Cream & Rollover Reaction & Liquid & 12 & 129000 \\
        Juicy Lip Balm & Rose All day & Stick & 4 & 139000 \\
        Lip Color & Runa Beauty & Stick & 5 & 138000 \\
        Lip Care & Sensatia Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 60000 \\
        Coconut lip sleeping balm & Tiff Body & Liquid & 1 & 69000 \\
        delight tony tint & Tony Moly & Liquid & 3 & 28000 \\
        Exclusive Matte Lip Cream & Wardah & Liquid & 20 & 62000 \\
        Colorfit Velvet Matte Lip Mousse & Wardah & Liquid & 14 & 73000 \\
        Everyday Moisture Lip nutrition & Wardah & Stick & 2 & 27000 \\
        Color Fit Ultralight Matte & Wardah & stick & 5 & 43000 \\
        The Simplicity Love You tint & Y.O.U & Liquid & 6 & 45000 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{center}

\subsection{Sampling}
Momoh. 0 (2021) stated that a population is a distinguishable group of people, whether that group is a nation or group of people who represent a characteristic. In this research the population is all the population data of popular lip products in Indonesia including several types. Whereas sampling is a technique for selecting individual members or a subset of the population in order to make statistical inferences and estimate population characteristics. From the population of 50 lip products, divided by five variables which are lip product, brand, type, shades and price. There are four methods of sampling which are random, stratified, systematic and cluster sampling. Stratified sampling method is used to determine the sample in this research by dividing the population into subgroups based on the brand. There are 35 data collections for samples.

The confidence interval is \qty{95}{\%} with level of significance one-tailed test is 0.025 and level of significance two-tailed test is 0.05 . Below is the table showing the sample.

%%%% in table are considered comments/suggestions give above
    \begin{longtblr}[
    caption={Sample of Lip Products in Indonesia},
    label={Table2}  ]{cells = {font=\small}, % <---
                      colsep=3pt,
                      colspec={@{}X[l]  % <---
                                  l l  
                                Q[c, si={table-format=2.0}] % <---
                                Q[c, si={table-format=6.0}] % <---
                               @{} }, 
                      row{1} = {guard, font=\bfseries, m},
                      rowsep=1pt, % <--- 
                      rowhead=1, 
                      }
    \toprule
        Lip Product 
            & Brand 
                & Type % <--- changed name    
                    & Shades 
                        & Price     \\
    \midrule
        nivea lip balm soothe \& protect % changed to small cap letters
   & Beiersdorf & Stick & 1 & 29000 \\
        Extra lip tint & Bobbi Brown & Stick & 7 & 345000 \\
        Perfect Matte Lip Coat & Dear Me Beauty & Liquid & 6 & 129000 \\
        Creamytint & Emina & Liquid & 5 & 44000 \\
        Matte Lip Liquid & ESQA & Liquid & 7 & 165000 \\
        Dear Darling Water gel tint & Etude House & Liquid & 10 & 35000 \\
        Organic lip balm & Eucalie & Stick & 1 & 79000 \\
        lip and cheek dual use liquid & Focallure & Liquid & 7 & 129045 \\
        Melted Matte Lip Sheen & Goban & Liquid & 5 & 78000 \\
        Tinted lip balm + UV filter & HALE. & Stick & 3 & 98000 \\
        Urban Lip Cream Matte & Implora & Liquid & 12 & 24000 \\
        Beauty Lip \& Cheeck Crayon & Indoganic & Crayon & 3 & 129000 \\
        Vivid oil tint & Innisfree & Liquid & 10 & 150000 \\
        Metallic Lip Cream & Inul Beauty & Liquid & 4 & 89000 \\
        Infalible Pro Matte Lip Liquid & L'oreal & Liquid & 4 & 150000 \\
        Intense Matte Lip Cream & Liquid & Liquid & 12 & 110000 \\
        Longlasting Matte Lip Cream Metalic & LT Pro & Liquid & 3 & 97500 \\
        Ultra Light Lip Stain & Luxcrime & Liquid & 5 & 109000 \\
        Dew tinted 6hr lip moisturizer & Mad for & Stick & 3 & 99000 \\
        magnifique lip tint & Madame Gie & Liquid & 8 & 23000 \\
        Powestay Transfer Proof Matte & Makeover & Liquid & 8 & 123000 \\
        Sensational Liquid Matte & Maybelline & Liquid & 10 & 69000 \\
        Hydra Lip Cheek Tint & Mineral Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 51900 \\
        The one A-Z lip balm SPF 25 & Oriflame & Stick & 2 & 139000 \\
        Lip Cream & PIXY & Liquid & 16 & 53700 \\
        2 in 1 color tint & Purbasari & Liquid & 3 & 38500 \\
        Lip Cream Series & Raiku & Liquid & 13 & 118000 \\
        SUEDED! Lip \& Cheek Cream & Rollover Reaction & Liquid & 12 & 129000 \\
        Juicy Lip Balm & Rose All day & Stick & 4 & 139000 \\
        Lip Color & Runa Beauty & Stick & 5 & 138000 \\
        Lip Care & Sensatia Botanica & Liquid & 4 & 60000 \\
        Coconut lip sleeping balm & Tiff Body & Liquid & 1 & 69000 \\
        delight tony tint & Tony Moly & Liquid & 3 & 28000 \\
        Exclusive Matte Lip Cream & Wardah & Liquid & 20 & 62000 \\
        The Simplicity Love You tint & Y.O.U & Liquid & 6 & 45000 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}



As you see, there is no need to insert any vertical space for correct showing of table.

Well, through comments I got to know that the problem is mainly due to my texlive being 2021 version rather than latest one.
But, I was able to find a workaround by accident. Just add \vspace{3pt} after the Sampling paragraph before table. For some reason the table automatically comes up.
